# How to calculate remainder value of a fraction

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions

Question:

Four brothers split a sum of money between them. The first brother received 50% of the total, the second received 25% of the total, the third received 20% of the total, and the fourth received the remaining $4. How many dollars did the four brothers split?

What I understand:
15 percent of the value is $4
The total value should be the remaining 85% plus the value of the 15% (4).

Confused about:
How do I calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake. $4$ dollars corresponds to $5$ per cent of the total, so the total is $\frac{100}{5}\times 4$ dollars.